# I don't see the concurrency property in Spring docs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm migrating my application from Spring Boot 2.4 to Spring Boot 2.7, and Spring Cloud to 2021.0.3.

I came across this situation. I am now using spring-cloud-stream package version 3.2.3, looking at the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-%20stream-binder-rabbit.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties), it has no reference to the *spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.**concurrency*** property that I use, it is quoted in **exclusive** and **maxConcurrency** properties, these in the settings of my application.yml also do not appear.

Is the documentation correct? If so, shouldn't the org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.ConsumerProperties class be consistent with the documentation?

Comment: I think the class is ok, because it's from the parent package spring-cloud-stream. The specific binder is not guaranteed to implement all the configuration options present on the consumer and also each binder has it's on properties to setup (example RabbitProperties from spring-cloud-stream-rabbit). You can try to open a documentation issue on the spring-cloud-stream repo, asking to add this information or to clarify the doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings..consumer.concurrency

`concurrency` is a common property for all binders, it is not rabbitmq specific.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.concurrency
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties

Comment: I understand now, thanks Gary!